Wildfly and Nginx - 404 not found
Environment:

VPS:
. Java, MySQL, Wildfly 31 server, Nginx 1.14.1 and Certbot.

My conf file:
server {

        server_name itcmedbr.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://ipaddress;
                proxy_ssl_server_name on;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/itcmedbr.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/itcmedbr.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = itcmedbr.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        server_name itcmedbr.com;
        listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}

I 've created itcmedbr.conf in conf.d directory and this file was updated by certbot, when I type itcmedbr.com in my browser I'm receiving this error "404 not found" but View site information button show that connection is secure. When the wildfly deploy a war file the result is loaded in the deployments directory, all that I read of nginx location parameter of nginx.conf is showed an path to webapp that normaly is for var/www directory of apache tomcat, then the question is how nginx works with Wildfly?  How to configure the path of my webapp that is located in the wildfly deployments directory?
Thanks and best regards.

I solved the errors of my wildfly configuration but I still receiving "404 Not found" as result of itcmedbr.com in my the browser, I don't have any type of error in wildfly log or nginx log, after change to domain mode was created a directory with my jsp pages, web-inf and meta-inf.
Nobody to tell me why this occur?
Thanks.
